# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-tasks-api

when i try to access google calendar or tasks api from my application in PRD it throws the following error:

The redirect URI in the request: http://MyApp.com/ManageEvents.aspx did not match a registered redirect URI

Learn more
Request Details

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
response_type=code
access_type=online
redirect_uri=http://MyApp.com/ManageEvents.aspx
display=page
client_id=8827312348664.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

The thing is that i have registered http://www.MyApp.com/ManageEvents.aspx under my "Redirect URI's" in the app engine/console but i still get the error message. the worst part is that when i tested it a day ago it worked, then i test it now and it doesnt. it seems to work on some machines and not others. what gives?

any response would be most welcome.
cheers.

Comment: Is it http or https? It must match exactly.

Comment: Two things to try:

1. Sometimes you have to wait a while before changes to the google developer's console take effect.  It can be immediate or it can take a while.
2. If time doesn't solve the problem, you sometimes need to create a new client id.  I don't know why this works, but often, it solves the problem.